# How can I make this ItemListener for JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing

**I'm trying to use sizeP for array. Make totBill equal to (array element selected) of margheritaPizza. But it does not change value at all. As if the listener is doing no good.**

Is there something wrong in my ItemListener or the code as a whole? Any help will do. I'm just a 3rd year college and having troubles with this because I am self taught.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class tryyy extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    final int [] margheritaPizza = {258, 450, 799, 999};
    int totalBill = 0, sizeP = 0;
    
    ButtonGroup pType = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton mPizza = new JRadioButton("Margherita Pizza");

    ButtonGroup pSize = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton small = new JRadioButton("Small");
    JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
    JRadioButton large = new JRadioButton("Large");
    JRadioButton xl = new JRadioButton("Extra Large");
    
   
    JLabel pizzaTypes = new JLabel ("Pizza Types");
    JLabel sizes = new JLabel ("Sizes                 ");
    
    JTextField totBill = new JTextField (5);
    
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel pTypePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel pSizePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel sizePanel = new JPanel();
    
    public tryyy(){
        super ("PIZZA MENU");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(mainPanel);
        add(pTypePanel);
        add(sizePanel);
        add(pSizePanel);
                
        setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.LEFT));
        
        mainPanel.add(pizzaTypes);
               
        pType.add(mPizza);

        sizePanel.add(sizes);
        
        pSize.add(small);
        pSize.add(medium);
        pSize.add(large);
        pSize.add(xl);
        pSizePanel.add(small);
        pSizePanel.add(medium);
        pSizePanel.add(large);
        pSizePanel.add(xl);
        
        add(totBill);
        totBill.setText("$" + margheritaPizza[sizeP]);
        totBill.setEnabled(true);
        
        small.addItemListener(this);
        medium.addItemListener(this);
        large.addItemListener(this);
        xl.addItemListener(this);
        
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        pTypePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
        pSizePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));
        sizePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
        small.setSelected(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tryyy aFrame = new tryyy();
        aFrame.setSize(325,500);
        aFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int select = e.getStateChange();
        if(source == small)
                if (select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    sizeP = 0;
        else if (source == medium)
                if (select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    sizeP = 1;
        else if (source == large)
                if (select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    sizeP = 2;
            else
                if (select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    sizeP = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy but your specific problem occurs because you don't change totBill text when button events occur. Try this.

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == small){
            sizeP = 0;
        } else if (source == medium) {
            sizeP = 1;
        }else if (source == large) {
            sizeP = 2;
        }else {
            sizeP = 3;
        }
        totBill.setText("$" + margheritaPizza[sizeP]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this later on and hope it fixes the problem. Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- You are not reassigning the correct text to the `JTextField` in your `ItemListener`. You are only changing `pSize`, but this will have no effect on the displayed textfield.
- Always use braces, because otherwise you will run into behavior that might be unexpected. (In this case, in your if-blocks)
- Class names start with uppercase letters.
- You may want to revisit your layout, because right now, it is quite messy. In the end, you should not use fixed sizes for your components and let the layout manager do the work for you. ( Maybe check out the [Using Layout Managers Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html))
- For the selection of "Pizzas", maybe a `JComboBox` is more suitable if there will be more.
- Maybe it's more fitting for you to use an `ActionListener` in combination with the `setActionCommand()` method on your Radio Buttons. (But this is probably opinion-based and will depend on your further use case)

See example below:

```
public class Try extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ....
    ....
        small.setActionCommand("$" + margheritaPizza[0]);
        small.addActionListener(this);
        medium.setActionCommand("$" + margheritaPizza[1]);
        medium.addActionListener(this);
        large.setActionCommand("$" + margheritaPizza[2]);
        large.addActionListener(this);
        xl.setActionCommand("$" + margheritaPizza[3]);
        xl.addActionListener(this);

    .....
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        totBill.setText(e.getActionCommand());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind and try to do as you suggested. Thank you so much.